# How to format DropDownList's  ListItem from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following is not working. It shows as unformatted text.

```
ListItem li = new ListItem();
li.Attributes.Add("style", "font-style:italic");         
li.Text = "Select product";
li.Value = "0";
ddlProducts.Items.Add(li);
```

Comment: Have you tried: li.Attributes["style"] += "font-style: italic";?

Comment: It is not working. Tried just now.

Comment: I think IE (newer versions may be different) ignores font styles on dropdownlists. This might be why it's having no effect. The code you've written looks correct. Certain browsers render a dropdownlist using an OS level style, which is unaffected by CSS.

Answer (score 3):

See this [link.](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-select-optgroup-options-css/)

Not all browsers support font-style for option

Answer (score 0):

dropdownlist renders html  with an  for every ListItem. And
 doesn't support font settings in style. Try using javascript.